# Update gearing Atom 77 freewheel 1989?

Tags: peugeot

I have an old French Peugeot 12 speed (pbn) that I would love to have an easier (is that how I say?) lowest gear? The hills on southern France really kills my knees today.

The freewheel says atom 77 and the hub says Maillard 1989. Its 14 - 24 tooths. Would it be possible to change the freewheel to a 28 toots or will I need to upgrade everything then?

I read on Sheldon Browns web page that many derailleurs could handle 28t and that freewheels were available to buy (~30usd). IF it wasn't a French thread freewheel. Can I know that without opening it an measure the threads?

Thanks in advance!

[image: atom 77 freewheel]
[image: Maillard hub]

Comment: If you are in France you may find a dealer who has still some old 6 speed freewheels stored away. Atom is a now defunct brand that was quite common in the 80s. Maillard is still around.

Comment: Thanks! How can I be sure it's French threaded?

Comment: They'll have to remove the freewheel and check. But it will most certainly fit since the freewheel manufacturer Atom was bought by Maillard, the hub manufacturer. (And it's France...)

Comment: Getting the french to not use french standards is about as common as a french person  speaking english (which is to say, pretty uncommon)